# MysqlMembership Membership.ValidateUser Deadlock issue when under load

Tags: .net, mysql, wcf, deadlock, httpmodule

I have a WCF Webservice with a custom httpModule which I use to do UserName/Password authentication against the MysqlMembership.

```
public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.AuthenticateRequest += new EventHandler(this.OnAuthenticateRequest);
        application.EndRequest += new EventHandler(this.OnEndRequest);
    }

    public void OnAuthenticateRequest(object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
            ...
            ...

            if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
            {
```

When I started loadtesting my service, I came across a perplexing problem.  Requests randomly fail the Membership.ValidateUser call.  I am using the same username/login for each thread in my load tester.  Here is the error:

```
  [MySqlException (0x80004005): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction]
  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() +506
  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32&amp; affectedRow, Int32&amp; insertedId) +450
  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force) +131
  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() +1216
  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +2191
  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +27
  MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +1092

  [ProviderException: An exception occurred. Please check the Event Log.]
  MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +1481
  MyApplication.UserAuthenticator.UserNameAuthenticator.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) in C:\Develop\MyProject\MyProject.UserAuthenticator\UserNameAuthenticator.cs:123
  System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
  System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)      +270
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
AFrieze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validate user locks the row in order to increment the invalid password attempts, if the password turns out to be invalid:

> If an incorrect password is supplied to the ValidateUser method, the
>   internal counter that tracks invalid password attempts is incremented
>   by one. This can result in the user being locked out and unable to log
>   on until the lock status is cleared by a call to the UnlockUser
>   method. If the correct password is supplied and the user is not
>   currently locked out, then the internal counters that track invalid
>   password and password-answer attempts are reset to zero. For more
>   information, see the MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts and
>   PasswordAttemptWindow properties.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.validateuser.aspx

Since you are using the same user for all request you can get a deadlock.

Comment: The Actual error was deadlocking on the lastActivityDate, but same effect.